# Why is my loadUserByUsername not working?

Tags: hibernate, authentication, spring-mvc, spring-security

I'm using Spring Security 3.  I have my own authentication provider.

Here is what I have so far:

**security-app-context.xml**

```
<authentication-manager>
    <authentication-provider user-service-ref="detailsService" />    
</authentication-manager>

<beans:bean id="loginSuccessHandler" class="com.myapp.security.LoginSuccessHandler" />
<beans:bean id="loginFailureHandler" class="com.myapp.security.LoginFailureHandler" />
<beans:bean id="detailsService" class="com.myapp.security.UserDetailService" />
```

**UserDetailService**

```
public class UserDetailService implements UserDetailsService {

    private DataSource dataSource;

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        String hql = "from Users where username = :username";

        List<Users> list = null;

        try {
            IO io = new IO("common_web");
            IOQuery query = new IOQuery();
            query.setStatement(hql);
            query.setParameter(new IOParameter("username", username));

            list = io.runQuery(query);

            if (list.isEmpty()) {
                return null;
            }

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

        // THIS WORKS.  I HAVE A VALID USER FROM DB
        return (UserDetails) list.get(0);
    }
}
```

This code is just a simple example.  At the point of "// THIS WORKS..." I do have a `Users` record from our database.  But when I return this object, I'm still not being authenticated.

Note that `Users` is a Hibernate table object.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just because a UserDetails is returned does not mean that you will be authenticated. The DaoAuthenticationProvider does a number of checks to ensure that the user returned should be authenticated. For example, it ensures that the username and password match, the account is not expired, the account is not locked, etc. A common problem is returning a UserDetails that does not contain any GrantedAuthority's which results in a UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken that indicates the user is not authenticated.

Have you tried enabling debug logging for org.springframework.security? This might explain what is wrong. If you are unfamiliar with logging, Spring (and Spring Security) use commons-logging and you can find a [logging guide](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/overview.html#d0e743) in the Spring reference.

PS As documented in the UserDetailsService interface, [loadUserByUsername](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/core/userdetails/UserDetailsService.html#loadUserByUsername%28java.lang.String%29) should never return null. Instead throw a UsernameNotFoundException

Answer (score 0):

Since `Users` class is implementing the `UserDetails` interface, make sure that you are returning a `GrantedAuthority` list instead of null from getAuthorities method. Also, other validation methods should return appropriate values to indicate that user is valid. For example:

```
@Override
public List<GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {

    return AuthorityUtils.createAuthorityList("VALID_USER_ROLE");
}  
@Override
public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean isEnabled() {
    return true;
}
```